# python read big file using izip_longest not working

Tags: python

I am new to python, currently, I am trying to read a big file.  I sepereate a big file into mulitple chunks:

Here is the code to do that:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fill_value=None):
    """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"""
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fill_value)
```

And then I use this to read each line in the chunk:

```
for chunk, lines in enumerate(line_gen, start=1):
```

I find it works on the big file does not contain empty line in the end, if it has, it does not work.

Could someone tell me how to make it work on files has empty line in the end ?

Comment: What is the input for your function? And an example output as well? Please help us help you

Comment: @AnandSKumar yep, my input is the the file

Comment: `the the file` is not helpful at all, update your question with the input (don't just say `file`) we cannot assume what the file would contain and what it wouldn't , best would be to update the question with the parameters of the function `grouper` and exactly what is the output you are expecting